# Stream a Video output via ffmpeg Pipe into a Python Script for analisis. How to pipe into python?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

I'm working on a script in conjunction with other libraries which requires an frame or image in an RGB24 format. For improved compatibility I have decided to allow for an external pipe to stream frames into this program. Changing the device or source every time with in the code can become tedious and using a parser to simply specify the source leads to syntax errors. Example:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="OEM Device" a.mpg
```

works exactly how you would think. However in an subprocess in python

```
pipe = sp.Popen('ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="OEM Device" a.mpg'.split(),...
```

**Edit** *I have tried to manually split. 'video="OEM Device"' didn't work inside python either.*

Leads to ' **Invalid argument "OEM** Separating *OEM* and *Device* as two different variables/arguments. I have tried the alternative name as well.

Which led me to believe

**"**

is the problem.
Which led me to piping the video stream into python via the terminal.

```
ffmpeg -i a.mpg -f image2pipe -vcode rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 - |python myscript.py
```

This is what I have in the Script.

```
import subprocess as sp
import numpy
import sys
import os
pipe = sp.Popen('ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -an -vcodec rawvideo -i - -f image2pipe -pix_fmt rgb24 -an -vcodec rawvideo -'.split(), stdin=sys.stdin, stderr=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE)
#Assumeing 720x576 resolution 
raw_img = pipe.stdout.read(720*576*3)
image = numpy.fromstring(raw_img, dtype='uint8')
img_load = image.reshape(576, 720, 3)
```

I know the Above **pipe** is not needed and can probably be replaced by.(Which I have tried)

```
raw_img = sys.stdin.read(720*576*3)
```

Regardless of the two it ordinarily gives output, which  results in

```
image.reshape(576,720,3)
```

to receive irregular dimensions and never the required 720x576 as is being specified. I have to admit this is the first time using pipes with python. As I understand stderr is Suppressed As I have specified *image2pipe*.

*How can I let ffmpeg to either give python the required dimensions or give an subprocess the syntax ,which allows **"** in the given command without splitting the values or causing syntax errors?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing a string and then `.split()`-ing it, just pass a proper array to start with:

```
.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-f', 'dshow', '-i', 'video="OEM Device"', 'a.mpg'], ...)
```

The command you are calling needs to see `video="OEM Device"` as a single element in its args array, so you need to pass it as a single element to the `Popen` args array.

Comment: Didn't workout either as "OEM Device" gets passed to ffmpeg and not the name without **"**  , I also tried to remove both. Only followed with error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Didn't workout either as "OEM Device" gets passed to ffmpeg and not the name without **"**  , I also tried to remove both. Only followed with error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'. **edit** turned out to be my typo. I was previously trying to use video= and "OEM Device" as separate splits. Also pipe.stdout.read() required an declaration which I missed for a second before realizing my fault. Thank you Grisha Levit.

Comment: [dshow @ 00000000025530c0] Could not find video device with name ["OEM Device"] among source devices of type video.
video="OEM Device": I/O error

Answer (score 0):

Curtesy of @Grisha Levit: The Answer was to simply remove **"**
Instead of writing a string and then .split()-ing it, just pass a proper array to start with:

```
.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-f', 'dshow', '-i', 'video=OEM Device', 'a.mpg'], ...)
```

The command you are calling needs to see 'video=OEM Device' as a single element in its args array, so you need to pass it as a single element to the Popen args array.